# C/C++ : how to get the number of bytes addressed by one address

Tags: c++, c, memory, byte

On most x86 / x86_64 architectures, one address points to one byte.
But on the micro controller I'm using, an address points to 2 bytes.

Is there a way to know the number of byte an address points to ?
(like in macro or something else)

Comment: There's nothing you could do with this information were you to get it that would have well-defined behavior.

Comment: the question is not why I need this. -.-'

Comment: @hl: Which is why that's not an answer.

Comment: What is the micro controller you are using?

Comment: I know the information for the micro I'm using, I'd just like have portable code

Comment: I'm interested to know because I've never heard of a micro-controller addressig multiple bytes - I wanted to know exactly what you mean by "an address points to 2 bytes"

Comment: Okay, I just think I was really tired this morning...
byte = 16 bit in my mc, and sizeof(char) == sizeof(short)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"byte" means "the smallest addressable unit" on a machine; one address always identifies one byte. On some machines, a byte will be 8 bits; on others, it could be 32 bits.<sup>1</sup>

The C standard defines `char` to be the smallest addressable unit on a machine<sup>2</sup>; and the macro `CHAR_BIT` for the number of bits in that unit. It will be a macro in `<limits.h>` / `<climits>`.

---

<sup>1</sup> C99 6.2.6.1 footnote 40 says:

> A byte contains `CHAR_BIT` bits, and the values of type `unsigned char` range from `0` to 2<sup>CHAR_BIT</sup>−1.

<sup>2</sup> Not strictly true but strongly implied by e.g. C99 6.2.6.1/4:

> Values stored in non-bit-field objects of any other object type consist of `n` × `CHAR_BIT` bits, where `n` is the size of an object of that type, in bytes.

which says that `sizeof(char) == 1`

Comment: One might add that at the hardware level, there may be different types of pointers.  I've worked on machines where `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`, because to address a byte, the machine needed additional information.

Answer (score 3):

The macro `CHAR_BIT` evaluates to an integer which is the number of bits in a `char` on the target platform.

The point of `char` is to capture the smallest single addressable unit of memory on the target platform. This is often called a "byte", and does not have to be 8 bits.

The proper term for an 8-bit quantity is [an octet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29). In practice, 8-bit bytes are so common that the term has shifted in meaning.

You get access to the `CHAR_BIT` macro by doing

```
#include <limits.h>
```

Comment: No idea why this was down voted. I normally am not the pity up vote person, but it is correct, so +1

Comment: @BillyONeal You're welcome, I didn't check the standard but it was scary with `^`, risk of confusion with bitwise xor.